# How can I increase the available memory for a process on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-mobile

The amount of virtual memory available to my process is 32MB, although there's plenty more actual RAM. Is there a way (e.g. a function call or project property) that can increase this limit? I am finding the limit very....limiting.

I am looking at the usage by calling [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). If there was something that could set the `dwTotalVirtual` member that's the kind of thing that would help.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to increase that.  Windows CE 5.0 and earlier had a hard, baked in limit of 32MB of virtual memory for any of the supported 32 simultaneous processes.  It's part of the kernel.

Now it is worth mentioning that not all allocations come from that 32MB.  From the docs (and experience):

> If you call [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908768.aspx) with dwSize >= 2 MB, flAllocationType set to MEM_RESERVE, and flProtect set to PAGE_NOACCESS, it automatically reserves memory in the shared memory region. This preserves per-process virtual memory.

This means that you can VirtualAlloc large regions and use that without impacting your 32MB slot limitation.

Comment: Thank you. To confirm: is the only way to access this memory using WriteProcessMemory and ReadProcessMemory?

Comment: Technically the answer is "it depends".  For CE 5.0 and earlier shared memory is not actually protected, so you can just read and write to the pointer that VirtualAlloc returned.  It's not the "correct" way to do it, it's only a fundamental flaw of the OS not protecting that memory that allows it to work. The flaw was corrected in CE 6.0, so direct pointer manipulation makes your code not portable to CE 6 or 7.